# How to show this sequence converges to 1?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $x\:>\:1$ and consider $a_n$ a sequence of positive numbers and $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(a_n\right)\:=\:0$

prove that: $$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(x^{a_n}\right)\:=\:1$$

I thought about the squeeze theorem because its easy to bound from below, but from above i really can't find something. tnx!

**edited**: NOT using logarithm rules or functions stuff.

Comment: anything to the zero power is equal to 1

Comment: @Bot That in and if itself doesn't prove anything, since we never raise anything to the zero'th power in this case.

Comment: $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$

Comment: @Bot: You can't just plug in $0$ willy nilly because it is the limit of the $a_n$'s...

Comment: @Bot Which we can only use once we know that exponentiation is (sequentially) continuous, and in a problem this basic, that fact would probably have to be explicitly stated.

Comment: limit of $a_n$ as n approaches $\infty$ is 0 so the limit of $x^0$ must be 1

Comment: What does $a_{\infty}$ even mean? Infinity is not a number...

Comment: I would use the $\epsilon$-definintion of the limit.

Comment: @Lukas can you explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = 0$, there exists a positive integer $N$ such that $0 < a_n < \frac{1}{2}$ for all $n \ge N$. If $b_n := x^{a_n} - 1$, then $b_n > 0$ for all $n$ and

$$x = (1 + b_n)^{1/a_n} \ge (1 + b_n)^{\lfloor\frac{1}{a_n}\rfloor} \ge 1 + \left\lfloor\frac{1}{a_n}\right\rfloor b_n > 1 + \left(\frac{1}{a_n} - 1\right)b_n > 1 + \frac{b_n}{2a_n}$$

for all $n \ge N$. Therefore, $0 < b_n < 2a_n(x - 1)$ for all $n \ge N$. Now it follows from the squeeze theorem that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} b_n = 0$, i.e., $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} x^{a_n} = 1$.

Comment: is it the Bernoulli's inequality you used? but how can you demonstrate that  $\frac{1}{a_n}$ is an integer?

Comment: Yes I did use Bernoulli's inequality, and I don't need $\frac{1}{a_n}$ to be an integer. I just need $\frac{1}{a_n} \ge 1$.

Comment: @user2637293 Look at the [Generalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality#Generalization) part.

Comment: interesting. but i'm affraid i can't use the generelization of Bernoulli's inequality because the proof of it , according to wikipedia , use derivation which i'm not allow to use. if you have an idea to prove it without derivation it will be great!

Comment: @user2637293 I've made an edit that uses the ordinary Bernoulli inequality. I have also used the floor notation $\lfloor x\rfloor$ to denote the greatest integer not exceeding $x$.

Answer (score 4):

If you are allowed to use logarithms, then you could say

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}x^{a_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{a_n\ln  x}=e^{\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\ln x}=e^0=1$

Answer (score 2):

For a fixed $a>1$ the function $f(x) = a^x$ is continuous. Hence if $x_n$ is a convergent sequence of real numbers:

$\lim_{x\to \infty}(a^{x_n}) = a^{\lim_{x\to\infty}x_n}$.

Thus the limit in question is $x^0 = 1$.

Comment: good job rephrasing my comment. =)

Comment: The point is that it is important to give the reasons behind it. It isn't true in general that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n) = f(\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n)$...i.e. you can't just plug in the limit of $a_n$ into $f$.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use continuity of the function $a \mapsto x^a$, then,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} x^{a_n} = x^{\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n} = x^0=1.$$

---

If you're not allowed to use that, <s>note that the sequence $(x^{a_n})$ is strictly decreasing</s> (this is actually unnecessary). I assume you've shown that $1 \le x^{a_n}$ for all $n$. For any $\epsilon>0$, choose $N$ large enough so that $x^{a_n}<1+\epsilon$ for all $n \ge N$. This is possible by choosing $N$ large enough so that $a_n \le \frac{\log(1+\epsilon)}{\log x}$ for all $n \ge N$, since $a_n \to 0$.

Comment: The sequence is not necessarily strictly decreasing...but we can choose a strictly decreasing subsequence of the $a_n$'s since we know the limit is $0$.

Comment: @fretty Oops, thanks, I will fix my answer.

Answer (score 0):

let m be a natural number ,now suppose $$a_{n}=\frac{m}{n}\\\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }a_{n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{m}{n}=0$$
$$x>1\\x^{a_{n}}=x^{\frac{m}{n}}=\sqrt[n]{x^m}\\$$if  we name $$x^m=X$$ 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\sqrt[n]{x^m}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\sqrt[n]{X}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }X^\frac{1}{n}\rightarrow 1$$

Comment: What if the $a_n$ are irrational?

Answer (score 0):

Since $a_n$ is positive and converges to $0$, for any $k\in \Bbb N$, there is an $N\in \Bbb N$ such that $a_n<\frac1k$. That means that there is a strictly increasing sequence $n_i$ of natural numbers such that $a_{n}<\frac1i$ as long as $n>n_i$.

So you can compare $x^{a_{n_i}}$ and $\sqrt[i]{x}$, where the last one converges to $1$ as $i$ goes to $\infty$.